# How do I Filter on the Outer Query in a SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery

I've executed the following query which returned me this table. I would now like to filter by Day = '27'. Where do I put the 'WHERE' clause to perform this filter?

[image]

```
SELECT
user_info.email,
extract(year from timestamp_seconds(time_stamp)) AS Year,
extract(month from timestamp_seconds(time_stamp)) AS Month,
extract(day from timestamp_seconds(time_stamp)) AS Day
FROM Mixpanel.events_log
JOIN Mixpanel.user_info ON user_info.user_id = events_log.user_id
WHERE time_stamp IN
(SELECT 
min(time_stamp) AS time_stamp
FROM Mixpanel.events_log
INNER JOIN 
Mixpanel.user_info on events_log.user_id = user_info.user_id
WHERE event = 'change_screen' AND screen = 'canvas'
GROUP BY user_info.email)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WHERE event = 'change_screen' AND screen = 'canvas' and extract(day from timestamp_seconds(time_stamp))=27
```

Another tip that often makes things easier is to use CTEs.

```
with myCTE as (
  SELECT
  user_info.email,
  extract(year from timestamp_seconds(time_stamp)) AS Year,
  extract(month from timestamp_seconds(time_stamp)) AS Month,
  extract(day from timestamp_seconds(time_stamp)) AS Day
  FROM Mixpanel.events_log
  JOIN Mixpanel.user_info ON user_info.user_id = events_log.user_id
  WHERE time_stamp IN
  (SELECT 
  min(time_stamp) AS time_stamp
  FROM Mixpanel.events_log
  INNER JOIN 
  Mixpanel.user_info on events_log.user_id = user_info.user_id
  WHERE event = 'change_screen' AND screen = 'canvas'
  GROUP BY user_info.email)
)
select * from myCTE where Day = 27
```

Comment: Awesome tip, this does make it so much easier. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would add:

```
and extract(day from timestamp_seconds(time_stamp)) = 27
```

to the outer query.

I think you should write the query using window functions instead of `in`:

```
SELECT email, Year, Month, Day
FROM (SELECT ui.email,
             extract(year from timestamp_seconds(el.time_stamp)) AS Year,
             extract(month from timestamp_seconds(el.time_stamp)) AS Month,
             extract(day from timestamp_seconds(el.time_stamp)) AS Day,
             COUNTIF(el.event = 'change_screen' AND el.screen = 'canvas') OVER (PARTITION BY ui.email)
      FROM Mixpanel.events_log el JOIN
           Mixpanel.user_info ui
           ON ui.user_id = el.user_id
WHERE day = 27;
```